# ¿Como editar un iframe externo?

Tags: html, jquery, css, web, iframe

He leído que se puede cambiar el contenido de un `iframe` externo por `jQuery` de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#el_iframe').load(function () {
            $(this).contents().find("p").css({'background-color':'red','font-weight':'bolder','color':'white'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

¿Es real? Existen otros medios permiten alterar un `iframe` externo?

Comment: Lo probaste? Te lanzo algun error?

Comment: lo probé no lanzo error pero no funciona